# Project Euler Number 1 perl

Tags: perl, for-loop, project

I am a beginner coder and I have started doing the Project Euler stuff from projecteuler.net, and am on problem #1. The problem is:

> If we list all the natural numbers below 10 that are multiples of 3 or 5, we get 3, 5, 6 and 9. The sum of these multiples is 23.
>
> Find the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below 1000.

I have the following code too:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $a;
my $b;
my $c = 0;
my $d = 0;
my $e;

for ($a= 0; $a < 1000; $a += 3 ) {
    $d = $d + $a;
}
for ($b= 0; $b < 1000; $b += 5 ) {
    $c = $c + $b;
}
$e = $c + $d;

printf "$e \n";
```

And my output is this:

> 266333

But I know for a fact that is wrong. Maybe it's going over common answers that 5 and 3 share, like 15 or 45.

Whatever it is, suggestions?

Comment: x is a multiple of y if y is <something> by x...

Comment: FYI with best practice - https://github.com/rai-gaurav/Data-Structures-and-Algorithms-Perl/blob/master/project_euler/problem_1/solution1.pl

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If two loops are involed, they both need some conditions inside to skip some iteration. Perhaps you could also think about an alternative solution using only one loop:

```
for (my $n = 1; $n < 1000; $n++) {
   if ( ... ) { # <--*
     $d += $n;
   }
}
```

It could be easier and less code repeatition.

Now we only need to figure out the key expression for that `if` statement. :-)

Comment: It works! I have to check if it (being $n) is divisible by 3 or 5. Now that I got it, I feel kinda dumb for not figuring it out .

Answer (score 2):

> Maybe it's going over common answers that 5 and 3 share, like 15 or 45

Yes that's exactly what's happening. You will need to prevent common multiples from being added to the total sum twice. Perhaps adding a conditional statement in one of your loops. (I'd rather not give out the exact answer and let you figure out how to do it)

Answer (score -1):

I think you're doing too much in one stage. Don't add the numbers as you go. Instead, get a list of the numbers that you're interested in and add them all up at the end.

Oh, and here's a little hint. If you're trying to store a list of things and you want no duplications - then the keys of a hash work great for that.